# custom structure directive in Angular2 documentation

Tags: angular

In the custom structure directive example at following link, what does TemplateRef and ViewContainerRef point to?

https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#unless

A Directive usually doesn't have a view. So would templateRef point to the HTML tag or Component the directive is attached to? Eg In the following code, the template is everything between `<p> ...</p>`? I read that `*` gets converted to `<ng-template>` so it could be the case.

```
<p *myUnless="condition">Show this sentence unless the condition is true.</p>
```

What is ViewContainerRef in the example? Generally I would add a `<ng-container>` as view container? Where does it come from in the example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This example

```
<p *myUnless="condition">Show this sentence unless the condition is true.</p>
```

is transformed by the compiler into

```
<ng-template [myUnless]="condition">
   <p>Show this sentence unless the condition is true.</p>
<ng-template>
```

So you can see now that `myUnless` directive is placed on the `ng-template` element and that's why it has access to the `templateRef`

> So would templateRef point to the HTML tag or Component the directive
>   is attached to?

It "sort of" points to the contents of the `ng-template` element the directive is attached to. Under the hood it references the embedded view definition created for the `ng-template` contents.

> What is ViewContainerRef in the example?

Any HTML element can act as a view container. So again, in this case the directive injects the view container that references directive host element.

The `ng-template` element is rendered as comment DOM node, so you will see that both `ViewContaineRef` and `TemplateRef` point to this comment node:

```
export class MyUnless {
  constructor(t: TemplateRef<any>, vc: ViewContainerRef) {
    console.log(t.elementRef.nativeElement.nodeName); // #comment
    console.log(t.elementRef.nativeElement === vc.element.nativeElement); // true
  }
}
```

Comment: Ok, but what is `ViewContainerRef` in the example? :) Thanks

Comment: It's a directive host element, a DOM comment node that `ng-template` tag is transformed into